# How can we manually install zoteros libre office plugin on linux ubuntu22.04 if we installed it via Software Center?

Tags: software-center, libreoffice, zotero

A relative installed Zotero using the software center and for some reason the libre office plugin was not automatically installed.

I read https://www.zotero.org/support/word_processor_plugin_manual_installation but calling `which` on zotero didn't return anything of interest. So I needed to look for the right file myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path you are looking for is `~/snap/zotero-snap/56/extensions/zoteroOpenOfficeIntegration@zotero.org/install`.

In that folder you will find `Zotero_OpenOffice_Integration.oxt` which you can then install by double clicking it as described in the manual installation tutorial.

Finding that file can be a bit bothersome for beginners so I hope this helps. I found it using `cd /` and then `sudo find . -name zotero`. This results in a list of folders/files containing zotero in its name. I quickly noticed that two results had `cache` in them, so I ignored them. The last result within `snap` was the path I mentioned above and it was the right one.