# Manually install Zotero plugin libre office extension fails

Tags: libreoffice, zotero

Due to the not working reinstallation procedure from Zotero preferences, I followed these [instructions to install manually the Zotero plugin for LibreOffice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1453162/how-can-we-manually-install-zoteros-libre-office-plugin-on-linux-ubuntu22-04-if). I am able to find the oxt file of the extension. But I receive an error message as follows, whatever the mode of execution (double click the file or install it from extension manager in LibreOffice):

'Add Extension(s):
/home/XXXXXX/.config/libreoffice/4/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages/lu18895ult3.tmp_/Zotero_OpenOffice_Integration.oxt
does not exist
'

My context:

- Ubuntu 22.04
- LibreOffice 7.3.7.2 from the deb repository
- Zotero 6.0.30

Comment: Are you sure that your LibreOffice installation is from the deb repository? Check with the command `which soffice`.

Comment: 'which soffice' gives '/usr/bin/soffice', I have also checked the deb origin from the Gnome software app: 'source Ubuntu(deb)'

Comment: Finally I created the requested folder manually, copied there the oxt file and ... it installed, but when tried to run, got an "obsolete plugin" error message